# how to undo "dnf --installroot" command in fedora linux?

Tags: fedora, dnf

I wanted to install a package under /mnt/data folder to do that i have used this commnad

`dnf --installroot=/mnt/data --releasever=/ install package_name`

But this command create a whole new linux root folder structure inside /mnt/data folder.
Now i want to undo that is there any way?

Comment: already tryed with DNF History Rollback ?

Comment: there is no dnf history for this command. last i can see for 18th march after that no history

Comment: StackOverflow angle isn't directly clear to me. Are you trying to install software that you wrote yourself?

Comment: no i have installed it. but the thing is it created a new root envt which i dont want. so now i want to kind of rollback